# dynamic array change size

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, dynamic

I created this function to change the size of the dynamic array

```
size = 4; //this is what size is in my code

int *list = new int[size] // this is what list 

void dynArray::doubleSize(  )
{

 int *temparray;
  int currentsize = size;
  int  newsize =  currentsize * 2;

  temparray = new int[newsize];

  for (int i = 0 ; i < newsize;i++)
  {
  temparray[i] = list[i]; 
   }

  size =  newsize; 
  delete [] list;
  list = new int[size];
  list = temparray;


  // this it help see if i made any changes
  cout << sizeof(temparray) << "temp size:\n";
  cout << sizeof(list) << "list size:\n";
  cout << size << "new size:\n\n\n";
}
```

I  want it to output the size of  array is the function each time it changes size.I know this can be done with vectors but I would like to understand how to do it with arrays

what can I do differently to make this happen.

Comment: What's `size`? what's `list`? How are you running this code? Also `sizeof(temparray)` and `sizeof(list)` will not return the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems in your code:

**Problem 1**

The following `for` loop accesses `list` using out of bound indices. Number of element in `list` is `size`, not `newSize`.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < newsize;i++)
{
   temparray[i] = list[i];
}
```

You need to change the conditionals to `i < size;`.

Then, you need to figure out how how to initialize the rest of the items in `temparray`.

**Problem 2**

The following lines cause a memory leak.

```
list = new int[size];
list = temparray;
```

You allocate memory using `new` and immediately lose that pointer in the second line.

**Answer to your question**

To print the new size, you can use:

```
cout << "new size: " << size << "\n";
```

However, I wouldn't recommend putting such code in that function. You are making your class dependent on `std::cout` for not much benefit, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You can't: the C++ Standard provides no mechanism to access dynamic array dimensions.  If you want to know them, you have to record them when creating the array, then look at the variables you set (much as you've got `size` hanging around for printing at the end of your program.